# i want different id for both table so when the new id is added my id value remains correct

Tags: mysql

I am running below query

```
select id,name from mine union select bet_id ,name from mine_bets
```

Output:

```
|----+------------+ |
 id | name       | 
|----+------------+ 
|  1 | Real Bets  | 
|  2 | Fake Bets  | 
|  3 | error Bets | 
|  1 | 100        | 
|  2 | 500        | 
|  3 | 600        | 
|----+------------+
```

**Question**: I want different id for both table so when the new entry is added  my id value remains correct

Answer (score 1):

`row_number()` can be used to assign a unique number to each row:

```
select row_number() over (order by table_order, id) as id, name 
from (
  select id, name, 1 as table_order 
  from mine 
  union 
  select id, name, 2
  from mine_bets
) as s
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ySkS2-VI)

Comment: can i do this without a union